# Samsung smart tv app - Navigation of tabs using keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard, controls, samsung-smart-tv

Hi I am creating the app for **Samsung smart TV**. Instead of remote, I want to use the **keyboard** . Is it possible to do the control using keyboard keys. I installed Samsung smart TV SDK 4.1. Is there any way to catch the keyboard keys?

Comment: Sure you can use the keyboard for controlling the application

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to these 2 threads on Samsungdforum:

- [USB Keyboard](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/df3455b529adf7c4?forumID=a44c9c78b565ea69)
- [Usb Keyboard Hidden key function](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/df3455b529adf7c4?forumID=b5fdbc28e6ab04bb)